# Prevent 2D Player from moving through wall

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make the basics of a top down game.

I currently have a Player sprite that has a Kinematic RigidBody2D applied to it with a box collider 2D. The scale of this sprite is (1,1).

The wall sprite has a box collider with a scale of (20,1).

To control the player I am using the following code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    void Start() {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            Vector2 move = new Vector2(0,1);
            rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + move);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            Vector2 move = new Vector2(0,-1);
            rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + move);
        }
    }
}
```

With the code above I can control the Player and move them up or down, when attempting to hit the wall below the Player does not hit the wall but instead travels through it as if it was not there.

I'm new to Unity so any other information that might be useful feel free to let me know and I'll update my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have colliders attached to your walls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Uncheck** `IsKinematic` property in the `RigidBody2D` component. That's because setting isKinematic to **true** makes your `gameObject` **NOT** get affected by any **physical** or **gravity** forces.

And also see if your **wall** is not marked as `IsTrigger`! Check that in the Collider component of your wall .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am following a different tutorial now but still encountering the same issue. This tutorial is moving the character using entity.positio rather than MovePosition.

I made your changes you suggest and I am left with this http://i.imgur.com/6FRQi7V.gifv

Comment: have u put the `BoxCollider2D` on the grass area ? If yes then make sure it is not `is trigger`...and also check ur player ..He should have `rigidBody2D` component attached to it  !

Comment: I personally have rather bad experiences with `MovePosition`. Try directly setting the `velocity` of your `Rigidbody2D`.

Comment: I agree with @lan H

Comment: or u can use `AddForce`  @HarryNewsome